# shareReplay and take operators - some question

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have 2 issues with rxjs and angular:

1. I used shareReplay with refCount = true and bufferSize = 1 as for caching things which is great, but then I saw following thing:
   Consider you have this:

   ```
   const sourceObs: Observable<...> = ...
    const sharedObs1 = sourceObs.pipe(
    shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1,refCount: true }),
    take(1)
    )

    const sharedObs2 = sourceObs.pipe(
    take(1),
    shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1,refCount: true }),

    )
   ```

When we do following:

```
  sharedObs1 .subscribe(() => {
    setTimoue(() => sharedObs1.subscribe())
    })
```

Then, sourceObs would be subscribed again, in the timeout callback handler, using a new ReplaySubject for multicasting... is it ok? or a bug?

When we do following:

```
   sharedObs2 .subscribe(() => {
    setTimoue(() => sharedObs2.subscribe())
    })
```

Then, sourceObs is not subscribed again, in the timeout callback
2)
I would like to say about angular guards:
In a canActivate function, if you define a single var like this:

```
`enter code here`const source$:Observable<...> = ...
`enter code here`const usedObservable$ = source$.pipe(shareReplay({ bufferSize: 1,refCount: true }))
```

Let's imagin now, usedObservable$ is saved once somewhere...
Then, let's say we define some route with a guard which as a canActivate, let's say you do this:

```
canActivate() {
return usedObservable$;
}
```

Then everytime we hit the route, the guard runs, thus, canActivate, but I saw that the source$ is subscribed again and again even if it is attached by shareReplay...
Now, I saw, in angular that they wrapped the result of canActivate with first:

```
... canActivateReturnedOBservable.pipe(**first**())...
```

Which is the reason for source$ to run every time, we hit the route.

I also opened a git discussion here, related only to rxjs, `https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/discussions/7067`

What Do you think?